# Main query disturb pre_get_post by category query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pre-get-posts, custom-post-type-archives

I've an archive page with custom post sorted by a custom field. I have two buttons that apply a filter by custom category. The result is not as desired. The correct number of results comes out, but the content of the posts does not match.

This is my pre_get_post in functions.php

```
function xgc_filter_archive( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()){
        if ( is_admin() ) {
                return;
        }
        if ( is_post_type_archive ('concerts') ) {
                if ( 'cat' === $_GET['getby']  ) {
                            $taxquery = array(
                                    array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'categories_concerts',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                                    ),
                            );
                            $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
                }
        }
        if ( is_post_type_archive ('obres') ) {
                if ( 'cat' === $_GET['getby']  ) {
                        $taxquery = array(
                                array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'categories_obres',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                                ),
                        )
                        ;
                        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'xgc_filter_archive');
```

And this is a bit of my template:

```
<section id="menu_categories_obres" class="py-2">
     <div class="filter-custom-taxonomy container justify-content-center">
      <?php
        $terms = get_terms( 'categories_obres' );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
          <a href="?getby=cat&cat=<?php echo esc_attr( $term->slug ); ?>" class="btn btn-md btn-primary mt-2" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?>
          </a>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="llistat_obres" class="py-3">
  <div class="container" style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <?php 
                // Variables
                // query
                $posts = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type'         => 'obres',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'meta_key'          => 'any',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'order'             => 'DESC'
                         ));
                if( $posts ): 
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

If I comment main query works fine but then I am not sorted as I want.

Thanks for the replies

**EDIT:**

Now, If i put this code on functions.php

```
function xgc_filter_archive( $query ) {
    if ($query->is_main_query()){
        if ( is_admin() ) {
                return;
        }
        if ( is_post_type_archive ('concerts') ) {
                if ( 'cat' === $_GET['getby']  ) {
                            $taxquery = array(
                                    array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'categories_concerts',
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                                    ),
                            );
                            $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
                            $query->set( 'post_type', 'concerts'  );
                            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
                            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data_del_concert');
                            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
                            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
                }
        }
        if ( is_post_type_archive ('obres') ) {
            if ( 'cat' === $_GET['getby']  ) {
                        $taxquery = array(
                                array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'categories_obres',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $_GET['cat'],
                                ),
                        )
                        ;
                        $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
                        $query->set( 'post_type', 'obres'  );
                        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
                        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'any');
                        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
                        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
            }
        }
            return $query;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'xgc_filter_archive');
```

IF I click the filter button goes well and the order too, but at the begining the order of all posts is wrong. This code isn't working well. Any suggest?

```
$posts_list = get_posts(array(
                    'post_type'         => 'obres',
                    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                    'meta_key'          => 'any',
                    'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
                    'order'             => 'DESC',
                     ));
            if( $posts_list ): 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the different variable names on the place of `$posts`. You should not use any of the global variable names for avoiding such incidents.

Also, call `wp_reset_query()` after fetching your data. This will reset the query to default.

For the list of global variables please refer to this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables).

Edit your query to read like this:

```
$posts_list = get_posts(array(
        'post_type'         => 'obres',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_key'          => 'any',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'DESC',));
if( $posts_list ): 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: Thanks BlueSuiter.

where I need to change the name variables and where should I add `wp_reset_query` ()?

thanks

Comment: BlueSuiter 
I changed & posts to $ posts_list and it worked !!! But now the sorting by the field 'ANY' does not work.

Comment: @JoanChaparro Is it a numeric value?

Comment: yes is a year. I edited the initial post,... some suggest? Thanks

Comment: Change `'orderby'  => 'meta_value',` to `'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',`

Comment: No, doesn't work. I put this on function.php and it works after applying filter but before order is not working!!
 `$query->set( 'meta_key', 'data_del_concert');`
 `$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );`

Comment: `$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );`

Comment: Sorry BlueSuiter I must not have explained well.
This works well for me now. What doesn’t work is the initial sorting of posts.

Comment: `$posts = get_posts(array( 'post_type'         => 'obres',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'meta_key'          => 'any',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'order'             => 'DESC'
                         ));
                if( $posts ): 
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` this query i guess

Comment: If i put this query, the first order is ok, but the filter doesn't work well, It give me the number of post I expected but not the post that have category filtered. It could be for `wp_reset_query()?`. Where should I add wp_reset_query ()?

Comment: Specify the category in arguments, then it will work fine.

Comment: Doesn't work. It's the same. When the page is loaded the post order it's not correct. When I've clicked the category buttons, it's fine.

Comment: Can I take a look at your website?

Comment: https://stupendous-narwal.localsite.io
Username: boundary
Password: agreeable

Comment: The problem is in order of Obres and Concerts section. 
Concerts should be sorted by date, from newest to oldest. and Obres from newest to oldest year.

Comment: What is the date format you are using for the `any` field?

Comment: it's a number for year and 20211119 Ymd for returned value in Concerts and 19/11/2021 d/m/Y for show. But after de button filter it works

Comment: i think it is better to store time stamp. what you say?

Comment: only for the year?

Comment: oh you are storing year, than it seems you have doing something wrong with the query. please share the exact query you are using on the front page.

Comment: Thanks BlueSuiter. EDIT in main entry are the two queries, for categories in the function.php and for the OBRES section.

Comment: Is this worked for you?